# How to automatically select a categorical variable based on calculated number in REDCap?

Tags: redcap

I am creating a REDCap tool which gives patients a numerical acuity score based on their medical history. Each numerical score also corresponds to a color code (Green 1-3, Yellow 4-6, Red 7+) that nurses use. Is there a way to automatically display the name of the color code based on the acuity score?

I wanted to use something like a calculated field but it apparently cannot return text answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a sufficiently recent version, you can use the `@CALCTEXT` action tag to return the colour code based on the value:

```
@CALCTEXT(if([acuity]<=3,'Green',if([acuity]<=6,'Yellow','Red')))
```

Another way (or if you don't have `@CALCTEXT`) is to have a calculated 'helper' field and use its value in a `@DEFAULT` action tag. So, a field `[acuity_code]` would have the calculation:

```
if([acuity]<=3,1,if([acuity]<=6,2,3))
```

Them, a field `[acuity_colourcode]` could have these options:

```
1, Green
2, Yellow
3, Red
```

And an action tag:

```
@DEFAULT='[acuity_code]'
```

`[acuity_colourcode]` must be on a different form or page, as piping into `@DEFAULT` requires that the value exists in the database on page load; it's not dynamic or performed in-browser like branching logic or a calculation. So `[acuity]` and `[acuity_code]` would be on one page, and `[acuity_colourcode]` would be on a subsequent page.